# way to separate non-class library into header and implementation

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, implementation

Let's say there is a library named test, the header "test.hpp" is like follows:

```
namespace test
{
  int myfun(int a);
}
```

And as for the implementaion, which style is better?

```
#include"test.hpp"
int test::myfun(int a){
  return a*a;
}
```

or

```
#include"test.hpp"
namespace test
{
  int myfun(int a){
    return a*a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Second one is more better. As it is easy to maintain.

Comment: Too opinion based, methinks. That said, I agree with @coder3101 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have multiple namespaces or nested namespaces in your header as :

```
namespace test{
namespace subtest{
   int Foo(int);
   //many other functions go here
} //namespace subtest
} //namespace test
```

And

```
namespace test1{
int Foo(int);
}
namespace test2{
int Bar(int);
}
```

In these cases you should always go with Second implementation as it makes your code more readable and easy to debug.

First one :

```
#include "test.hpp"
int test::subtest::Foo(int x){return x;}
//many other goes here
```

Look as the nesting increase everytime to define a function, you need to write fully specified name of the function (repeating namespaces again again).

Second one :

```
#include "test.h"
namespace test{
namespace subtest{
int Foo(int x){return x;}
//other go here
}
}
```

This solves namespace name repetition also you can easily refactor things. To debug or refactor a namespace's content simply jump to it's first declaration and change the things. You can also collapse the code under single namespace. (With most ide) making you code more beautiful.

---

Similarly for multiple namespaces

First one :

```
#include "test.hpp"
int test1::Foo(int x){return x;}
int test2::Bar(int x){return x;}
```

How difficult it gets to debug things. Moreover if under two namespace same function name occurs you will have good time debugging.

Second one :

```
#include "test.hpp"
namespace test1{
int Foo(int x){return x;}
}
namespace test2{
int Bar(int x){return x;}
}
```

All the declaration within a namespace will be together. So debugging and jumping within namespace will be ease.

**Also most open source projects use second implementation**